# Can a divisor of derivation be cancelled out

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose I have this equation:

$$
\frac{\partial N}{\partial x \partial t} = \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}
$$

Can I cancell $\partial x$ and become:

$$
\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. The closest you can get is to rewrite it as

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x }\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\right) = 0
$$ and "integrate it once" to get

$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} = C(t) $$ for some function $C(t)$. But this is really only roughly valid, and you'll need to have some additional assumptions/information about the differentiability of $N$ and $\phi$ and their domains in order to make it more rigorous.